# JVM -XX:+StringCache argument?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments

I was recently reading about all the JVM arguments available in JRE 6 [[Java VM Options](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp)] and saw this :

> -XX:+StringCache  : Enables caching of commonly allocated strings.

Now I was always under the impression that Java kept a pool of interned (correct word?) Strings and when doing something like String concatenation with literals it was not creating new objects, but pulling them from this pool.  Has anyone ever used this argument, or can explain why it would be needed?

**EDIT:** I attempted to run a benchmark, to see if this argument had any effect and was unable to get the Sun JVM to recognize it.  This was with:

```
java version "1.6.0_11"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_11-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b16, mixed mode,
sharing)
```

So I'm not sure if this argument works at all.

Comment: I think most string operations don't use interning. The interning is rather used by the JVM to store string values from the class files and avoid excessive memory consumption because of duplicates.

Comment: Great question. The sun docs are very unclear here. However, docs on interning are clear that it only operates under specific circumstances (string literals) so perhaps the JVM arg applies this behavior in a wider set of circumstances.

Comment: I can't find this option in the OpenJDK source. What do you suppose that means?

Comment: @mmyers: It is probably not supported in OpenJDK.  Sun states: "Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are not recommended for casual use. These options are subject to change without notice."

Comment: Perhaps a benchmark is in order?

Comment: In my job we've fond that Java 5 cannot be trusted to intern all strings it could (when we started hitting OutOfMemory exceptions). We had to add calls to .intern() here and there. Maybe this option solves this problem in Java 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find a single JVM that even accepts this supposed argument - so I guess there's not much else to say.

Comment: Oracle JRocket 6 ;)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionXX.html

Comment: You need -XX:+AggressiveOpts to enable many of the weird options, -XX:+UseStringCache including. Here is ref: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk7-dev/2011-April/002024.html

Answer (score 6):

I believe when used with `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` it enables the same `String` objects to be returned when creating the `String` with the same text (though not through `new String`, of course). There is a profile phase where a cache is build up, and after a point the cache is switched to read only. It gets higher scores in certain benchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

-XX:-UseStringCache works for me, strangely.

my jdk version should be 1.6.0_22

Answer (score 1):

I too couldn't get the above to work, but the latest JBB @ spec.org shows it's use: -XX:-UseStringCache. I'll have to re-run benchmarks to see if it makes a difference (an XML heavy app).

Answer (score 1):

I also have not been able to find a JVM which respects this setting; as commented the quality and thus usefulness of the documentation around JVM parameters is terrible, and yet for some reason seems to be an area where JVM vendors see room for competitive differentiation - although to be fair Oracle/Sun is by far the worst.

Anyhow if you find that your app in some particular area uses a small number of string values repeatedly then it is definitely sensible to use interning - by using the String.intern() method to return an intern-pool value. Note that you have to use the return value, this is not a side-effect on the original value.

As with all profiling/performance tweaks this needs to be done carefully with metrics and testing. It can be significant (has been for me) but if the pool of values is not small it degrades performance and you need to be aware that the pool of String values is held in the Perm Gen and so using it will affect memory usage, GC etc.

Answer (score 1):

As of JDK 8.0, this option has been removed.  It is unclear to me what, if anything, can be used as a replacement.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

> ```
>  -XX:+UseStringCache
>
>     Enables caching of commonly allocated strings. This option was removed from JDK 8 
>     with no replacement.
> ```