# String Pool(String and StringBuffer)

Tags: java

On some blog and site even on stack overflow, I can see similar ans for below question

```
    String s = new String("Test");
```

Will create two object as literal "Test" will take place in pool.

So how StringBuffer perform in below case.

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("BufferTest");
```

Is the literal "BufferTest" also take place in pool ?

if yes then how StringBuffer save String garbage collection ?

Comment: Have a look at this as well :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909848/how-does-java-implement-flyweight-pattern-for-string-under-the-hood

Answer (score 0):

`"BufferTest"` will take place in the pool because any `String` object does that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the literal "BufferTest" also take place in pool ?

Yes.

All literal strings are help in the string pool/

> if yes then how `StringBuffer` save `String` garbage collection ?

It doesn't need to.  A `String` corresponding to a string literal remains reachable so long as the class (or classes) that defined it is in existence / loaded.

Comment: But As per below code I think with every append call StringBuffer loosing reference of first.                                                                                                <br/>          ' StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();'
    '  sb.append("Test");'
     ' System.out.println(sb.toString());'
  
      sb.append("Test1");
      System.out.println(sb.toString());

Comment: Like I said, the `StringBuffer` doesn't need to keep a reference to it.  The reference for `"Test"` is placed in the string pool when the code is loaded, not when it is executed.