# Does Java implemented Flyweight design pattern with Strings?

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, memory, reusability

As per the GOF definition for "Flyweight", reuse\share similar kind of objects to reduce the memory growth.

If this is the case, java string object does the same right by using string constant pool. Then can we say that Java String implements the Flyweight design pattern? If not, why?

Comment: I think this might answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909848/how-does-java-implement-flyweight-pattern-for-string-under-the-hood

Comment: I looked into it, it doesn't have proper reason why not?

Answer (score 6):

> Can we say that, Java String implements the Flyweight design pattern?

Not really.  Or at best you can say that it *can* implement that pattern.

The string constant pool only contains `String` objects that correspond to:

- Java string >>literals<< in the source code,
- other compile-time string constants, and
- String objects that have been deliberately "interned" by an application or library method calling the `String.intern()` method.

Normal Java `String` objects are not created in the string pool.  Instead, they are created in the normal heap, and only "put into the pool" by a call to `intern()`.  This is for good reason.  If all strings were interned by default, it would increase GC overheads and/or the long-term memory footprint of a typical Java application.

(Note that Java 8 now has an optional [string deduplication feature](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/string-deduplication-new-feature-java-8-update-20-2/) in the G1 collector which saves space by combining the char arrays of strings that are equal.)

Comment: What do you mean by normal java strings? Every string in java is a constant correct? So it should create in Constant pool right?

Comment: I mean a String that is created by calling one of the string constructors or method (apart from `intern`).  The fact that strings are immutable does not mean they are (necessarily) created in the pool.

Comment: If you don't believe me, check the Java source code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java's string pool is a good example of the flyweight pattern. As stated by the [wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern):

> Another example [of this pattern] is string interning.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is correct but IMO your conclusion is not entirely correct. String _interning_ is an example of the pattern but that doesn't apply to "Java String" (term used by OP) as a whole.

Comment: Interning is closer to caching than flyweight. IMHO the lines are blurred here though.