# Java GC tuning for strings

Tags: java, string, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

Profiling the application I figured out that there are a lot of strings on heap.

In my situation, strings are created on heap and not interned and they are not literals.

Are there are specific GC tuning techniques to follow when the number of strings in the application are very high.

I stumbled across the GC settings **-XX:+UseCompressedStrings or -XX+UseStringCache** but not sure this will help. Did any body try these settings?

java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: In my experience, dont mess with the GC, it usually does a good enough job as it is

Comment: Most important is what you don't do -- don't, eg, repeatedly "break" a string into the next "token" and "the rest".  That's done amazingly often and can bring an app to its knees.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Related to `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`, you should have a look at this question: [Support for Compressed Strings being Dropped in HotSpot JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8833385/772000)

And, related to `-XX+UseStringCache`, have a look at : [JVM -XX:+StringCache argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049983/772000)

Btw. Java 7 comes with nice features that allow tuning of String cache when using the interned Strings. See `-XX:+PrintSTringTableStatistics` and `-XX:StringTableSize=n`. This way you can optimize the String cache size.

Comment: To clarify: the `PrintStringTableStatistics` prints a report of your string pool usage when the program terminates. For more info, see [*String.intern in Java 6, 7 and 8 – string pooling*](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/) by [Mikhail Vorontsov](http://java-performance.info/author/Mike/).

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 comes with a new GC feature -XX:+UseStringDeduplication.

After enabling this, GC would compare strings to find those with same char array value. Let's say `str1` & `str2` have the same char[], then GC would make str1 point to char[] of str2. This way char[] of str1 can be garbage collected and reclaim the memory. And since Strings are immutable, there is no risk of making multiple strings point to the same char[]

Comment: One note: you need to use G1 garbage collector to use `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication`.