# What is current status of Oracle Java HotSpot VM performance options (+UseStringCache, +UseCompressedStrings, +OptimizeStringConcat)

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I was reading [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html). I've seen some interesting VM switches, mostly pertaining to Strings - which is of great value to me since my app is doing some heavy String manipulation. Those are:

- `-XX:+UseStringCache`
- `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`
- `-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat`

I was wondering - are these switches on by default? What is real world experience in using them? Do they make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering String performance, have a look at the `-XX:+PrintStringTableStatistics` and `-XX:StringTableSize=`. Java 7 comes with nice features that allow tuning of String cache when using the interned Strings. This way you can optimize the String cache size.

And, a related String Performance Q/A: [Java GC tuning for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15909640/772000)

Answer (score 16):

To check defaults use

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

To find exactly what you want you can

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep UseCompressedStrings
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was looking for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 9):

I know that `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` was dropped in Java 7 on the basis it was too hard to support.

For Java 7 update 40

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep UseStringCache
     bool UseStringCache                            = false           {product}           
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2>&1 | grep OptimizeStringConcat
     bool OptimizeStringConcat                      = true            {C2 product}
```

Comment: I see that you posted similar question as I have last year. That basically covers what I needed to know :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on my check of JDK6u21, JDK7u21 and JDK8u191 using PrintFlagsFinal, we have the following values:

```
                               JDK6u21       JDK7u21       JDK8u191

-XX:+UseStringCache              false         false   <unsupported>
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings        false  <unsupported>  <unsupported>
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat        false          true           true
```